# Android component like the JQuery DataTables plugin? Stick it in a WebView?

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview, datatables

The jQuery Data Tables plugin is very good for presenting and manipulating tabular data.  I haven't been able to find a comparable Android component.  First, is there something turnkey comparable and I've just missed it?

Second, what is the Android best practice here?  Is it advisable to merge HTML5 GUI elements (via WebView or WebViewFragment) in along with native Android, or am I going to run into hidden gotchas, e.g., activity life cycle corner cases?

I realize that there are platform independent approaches like PhoeGap/Cordova.  This might still be a way to go, but I'm just a bit leery of the approach in general.